# Creating multiple custom blocks in drupal 8

Tags: 8

```
├── hello_world
│   ├── hello_world.info.yml
│   ├── hello_world.module
│   ├── hello_world.routing.yml
│   └── src
│        ├── Controller
│        │   └── HelloController.php
│        └── Plugin
│             └── Block
│                  └── HelloA.php
│                  └── HelloB.php
```

I have used the above file structure to create blocks in Drupal 8. Both the blocks, HelloA as well as HelloB works, but only one at a time. I see block HelloA, if I remove HelloB.php and see Block HelloB when HelloA.php   is deleted. I am trying to create multiple blocks. Please guide me. Thank you very much.

Comment: It likely if HelloA.php & HelloB.php are copies of each other (or some other template) they might have some overlapping shared config which Drupal's interpreting as the same definition. Check the `@Block` annotation as well as your namespace & class names.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much Shawn.

It was the `@Block` annotation. I was using same id for both the blocks.

```
/**
  * @Block(
  *   id = "show_state",
  *   admin_label = @Translation("Show State"),
  *   category = @Translation("POP")
  * )
  */
```